# Can I hide BIND mount points from DF?

Tags: linux, centos, mount, bind, df

Is there a formal way to hide the mount points of `BIND` from `df` (in CentOS 6.4) ?

It's ugly and distracting.

Apparently people have been complaining about it for a decade but I cannot seem to google an answer.

Thanks for any suggestions.

ps. I am referring to this

```
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/sda     ext4    /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
```

pps. maybe via some kind of hide rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d`  ???

Comment: "df --exclude-type=none" will do it, although that might hide other things too. On my ubuntu system, df already seems to ignore bind mounts, and I have to run "df --all" to see them.

Comment: Unfortunately on my Centos 6.4 install, exclude-type=none still shows named/chroot mounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df -T` that will show what types are those and then `df --exclude-type=XX`

Example:

```
$ df -T
(...)
bindfs  fuse.bindfs 1135335480 820951420 256723580  77% ...
$ df --exclude-type=fuse.bindfs
```